# How bad are sessions for my server performance?

Tags: php, performance, session, cookies

Php uses session to store a cookie on the client side and than matches that cookie name with a file on a server. Example:

```
PHPSESSID=kbn5gncbf1783uv4kpbg84gdq8
```

matches with the file (A FILE, not DATABASE) in

`/var/lib/php/session`

This means all the serverside cookie data is stored in files. Imagine having 50000 users on your site using persistent sessions (that don't get deleted after browser restart). This means 50000 files in `/var/lib/php/session`. How big of a performance hit are my users getting because the server needs to find and open a file on my harddrive?

Is it better performance wise to use regular client side cookies and then see if that cookie corresponds to a registered user entry in my database?

Comment: a) couldn't you just benchmark that yourself? b) don't you think that "load something from a local disk" is always leagues faster than "load something from a remote clients disk"?

Comment: a) I guess I could if had the users. b) Loading from a remote clients disk is always present, whether you use regular cookies or sessions. The question is about additional performance hit of searching through a folder to find a session file matching your user. Imagine grep going through 50000 files

Comment: well - you could just *create* the files yourself. and don't compare the performance of grep with direct file system functionality...

Comment: Could you please write down the algorithm php uses to create session files so that can recreate them with proper names? Because search appears to be name based and we want a proper bench mark

Comment: You CAN benchmark this yourself, there are tools that perform this very task. Additionally, this is not a programming question, you'd be better off @ serverfault / super user IMHO.